# Deleting the last row border after X amount of rows

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use some Javascript to detect if my table has greater than 25 rows if so I want it to delete the bottom border of the last row. I'm still a newb with Javascript but I'll post my attempt at it.

```
var rows = document.getElementById('myTableId')
    .getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
    .getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
if (rows >= 25) {
    var Accounts = document.getElementById('myTableId');
    var lastRow = Accounts.rows.length;
    lastRow.style.borderBottom = "none"
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: lastRow is just a number

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with pure css. Have a look at this:

```
tr:nth-child(25) ~ tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

this selector basically says 'the last row that follows after the 25th row', so it will only be triggered if your table has more then 25 rows.

A small fiddle to demonstrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/d39erod6/

Comment: By far the simplest and cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I did a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0sodxsfc/1/) with one way to accomplish this.

```
var rows = document.getElementById('myTableId')
    .getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
    .getElementsByTagName('tr');

if (rows.length >= 25) {
    var lastRow = rows[rows.length-1];
    lastRow.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].style.borderBottom = "none"    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I ended up using the CSS version but your version definitely taught me some things so it was appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This actually done with CSS.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

You can use Javascript to set the CSS property and then also modify it.

Comment: The OP wants the last child if there are more than 25 rows.